# Can I inject some "Component Level Service" in Parent Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I make some example with ViewChild - this is what i want to do with Inject.
[simple expamle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsgdzy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I try provide this service in parent component but i get different service. Next i try make [somethink like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-usorby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but i dont want to write provide section in my new Modules... I want just somehow inject service from child...

Comment: If you want it to be injected outside the component, why is it component-level?

Comment: @jonrsharpe hm... I want to use few this component in my parent component - so they need use diff data. And i want use some helpfull methods from this services (like loading info). I can do this with ViewChild but i want to know: posible do this with Injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inject something from "child's"  injection subtree with the help of read attribute

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponen, {read: TestService}) testS: TestService;
```

but it is being initialized in the after view init stage of the component and in most cases it will cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in dev mode or your view will not react properly to the update in prod mode.

It can still be used, but you should understand angular change detectionn and be carefull with usage of such non typical things

Comment: Its good variant, ty.